# Запись нескольких чисел в одну ячейку целочисленного массива

Tags: c++

Всем привет!

Допустим у меня есть некоторые массивы:

```
int NM[4] = {255,255,255,255}; // для 10-ой маски
int DEC_NM[4] = {}; // для 2-ой маски
```

В массиве `NM[4]` хранятся октеты маски сети.
Далее мне нужно перевести каждый октет из 10-ой СС в 2-ю СС, что делаю я вот-так:

```
int x;

for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--){
    x = ((NM[0] >> i) & 1);
    Memo2 ->Lines ->Add(x);
}
```

Тут получается только для первого октета перевод и я могу его вывести в `Memo2` только отдельными числами, т.е. на выходе просто отдельные восемь единиц.

Как сделать так, что бы эти отдельные восемь единиц были записаны в `DEC_NM[0]`, следующие восемь единиц второго октета в `DEC_NM[1]` и т.д.

Или нужно для каждого октета делать еще один массив на 8 элементов и потом их отдельно соединять в целое число!?

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите получить в `DEC_NM[i]` число, соответствующие `NM[i]`, которое, если его печатать `cout << DEC_NM[i]` будет выведено как битовое представление `NM[i]`? / imho проще всего не заморачиваться а сразу написать функцию печати битового представления и вызывать ее -- `print_bits(NM[i])`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос - Вам нужен bitset ([bitset cpp ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/bitset))
У него есть operator[] который даст вам доступ к каждому биту.

Вот пример кода:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <bitset>


int main() {

    int NM[4] = { 255,255,255,255 }; // для 10-ой маски
    std::bitset<8> DEC_NM[4] = {}; // для 2-ой маски

    for (auto i{ 0 }; i < 4; ++i) {
        DEC_NM[i] = NM[i];
    }

    for (auto i{ 0 }; i < 4; ++i) {
        for (auto j{ 0 }; j < 4; ++j) {
            std::cout << DEC_NM[i][j];
        }
        std::cout << "\t";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: если не трудно, можете пояснить что происходит в первом цикле и во вложенном!?

Comment: @КонстантинКлименко да, но сначала пару вопросов, вы запустили этот код? Он выполнил то что Вы хотели ? Вы прочитали про биотест?

Comment: Да я запустил код(выводит по 4 единицы), то что мне нужно он выполнил и прочитал про bitset, примерное понимание сложилось о принципе работы, но т.к. первый раз узнаю об этом классе, то нуждаюсь в разъяснении небольшом

Comment: @КонстантинКлименко ну битсет  даёт возможность хранить обратиться к каждому биту информации и посмотреть 0 там или 1 ) шаблонный параметр это количество бит. По циклам - в первом преобразуется ваш инт в битсет 255 в массив 11111111 во втором мы обращаемся к каждому бита битсета и выводим его. Чтобы много не писать прочитайте  http://cppstudio.com/en/post/5765/  Если ответ вас устраивает нажмите на птичку чтобу принять его )

Comment: дико извиняюсь, можно я сдесь вам вопрос задам!? Просто не могу задать отдельный вопрос

Comment: @КонстантинКлименко да просто бы спросили и все

Comment: Вот допустим у меня есть `bitset<8> BIN_REZ[4] = {};` и я знаю что внутри него хранится следующее `10000010 00000100 011001*00 00000000*`. Далее мне нужно поменять значение битов с 0 на 1 между звездочками. Я пробвал сделать это вот так: `int L = 32 - BIN_HOST[0].to_ulong();
 for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
  for(L; L < 31; L++){

     BIN_BROADCAST[L] = BIN_REZ[L].flip();

  }
    }`  , но на выходе у меня выдаются просто 4 нуля, т.е я так понимаю просто заменилось все на ноль. Пробовал и еще разные способы, но результата так и не достиг нужного.

Comment: после добавления единиц и выводе через .to_ulong() это так:  что в начале -> `130.4.100.0`. Что на выходе ->  `130.4.103.255`

Comment: @КонстантинКлименко у Вас неверный цикл. Внимательно посмотрите по какому параметру вы итерируетесь. Задавайте новый вопрос

Comment: ладно тогда по другому задам вопрос, возможно ли получить доступ допустим к последнему биту 3 элемента этого массива!?

Comment: @КонстантинКлименко да, BIN_REZ[3][7]